# many round white pieces and gray

Tags: set-identification

I don't see any parts that are unique here.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the number of [4515347: PLATE 4X4 ROUND W. SNAP](https://brickset.com/parts/4515347) in white, this bag is from

[75302: Imperial Shuttle](https://brickset.com/sets/75302-1/Imperial-Shuttle)

[image]